# UWP CreateFile2 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED on "NUL"

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-universal, createfile

I am trying to migrate some old stuff from WP8 to Universal Windows Platform with C++ extentions. The problems starts when I'm trying to use this code

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"NUL", 0, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
```

h is -1, and last error is 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
CreateFile is redefined that way:

```
HANDLE CreateFile(
_In_ LPCWSTR lpFileName,
_In_ DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
_In_ DWORD dwShareMode,
_In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
_In_ DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
_In_ DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
_In_opt_ HANDLE hTemplateFile
)
{
    CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extendedParameters;
    extendedParameters.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
    extendedParameters.dwFileAttributes = dwFlagsAndAttributes & 0x0003FFF7;
    extendedParameters.dwFileFlags = dwFlagsAndAttributes & 0xFF3C0000;
    extendedParameters.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
    extendedParameters.lpSecurityAttributes = lpSecurityAttributes;
    extendedParameters.hTemplateFile = hTemplateFile;
    return CreateFile2(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, 
dwCreationDisposition, &extendedParameters);
}
```

This code works on Windows Phone 8, but doesn't work on Windows 10. So, the question is - what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You are requesting to open a file in exclusive mode (*dwShareMode* is 0). Is this intentional? Does it also fail with a less draconian share mode?

Comment: Yep, it does the same thing if I write FILE_SHARE_WRITE, or FILE_SHARE_READ, or FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ. I think, the problem is hidden in some kind of permissions to application, but I didn't find any solution at all.

Comment: Device access is strongly checked against the capabilities requested in [the appx manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-devicecapability).  Kinda doubtful that they cover legacy MS-Dos devices, but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly, as it is described in [CreateFile2 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When called from a Windows Store app, **CreateFile2** is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the **[ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx)** or **[Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx)** directories. You can't open named pipes or mailslots or create encrypted files (**FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED**).

So while using `CreateFile2` function in UWP, we need to provide a path inside the [`ApplicationData.LocalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) or [`Package.InstalledLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) directories as the `lpFileName` parameter instead of just a file name like:

```
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ localFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^ path = localFolder->Path;
path += L"\\Test.txt";

CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extendedParams;
extendedParams.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
extendedParams.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
extendedParams.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN;
extendedParams.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
extendedParams.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
extendedParams.hTemplateFile = NULL;

HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile2(path->Data(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_ALWAYS, &extendedParams);
```

The second one is that we can't use `NUL` as the file name. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, **NUL**, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.
> Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see [**Namespaces**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces).

So, you can change your code like the following then there should be no error.

```
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ localFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^ path = localFolder->Path;
path += L"\\Test.txt"; //Replace with the name you want to use.

HANDLE h = CreateFile(path->Data(), 0, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to create file to "NUL". But thanks, your information is thery helpful.

Comment: Using CreateFile2 how to open  symbolic link of device (for example "\Device\00000011") ?

Comment: @RDX Sorry, I'm not familiar with hardware or device development, I'd suggest you ask a new question to see if there is someone can help you with this issue.